# Search string in SQL with action on table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I found on internet some stored procedure to search string in database, regularly it's used by table name.

My procedure contains a `SELECT` statement like this:

```
select distinct s.name  
from sysobjects s 
inner join syscomments c on c.id = s.id 
                          and charindex(@keyword,c.text) > 0 
where s.type IN ('V', 'P') 
order by 1
```

My action want more than this, I want to search table name with action on that like insert, update or select. It means only find table name(keyword) has action insert or update or select and show me where it's used (procedure name, view...)

Is it possible to do?

Comment: means you want to find table and then insert/update/delete on that table? pl. confirm..also on which version?

Answer (score 0):

First, dont use sysobjects and syscomments as they have been deprecated for quite some time now.

If you just care that the word appears in the object text, you can use a wildcard search like this

```
select top 100 *
from sys.sql_modules sm
inner join (select searchString = 'insert' union all
            select searchString = 'update' union all
            select searchString = 'delete') x
    on sm.definition like '%' + x.searchString + '%'
```

Comment: Hi Xedni, I get this message when run the statement: Invalid object name 'sys.sql_modules'

Comment: What version of SQL server are you running? I may have presumed incorrectly you were running an newer version of SQL. Regardles, the same wildcard join should work if you only have access to syscomments like in your original query with some slight modifications to field names.